# Compute natural log of survival function of a Gaussian in Python/numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

I can compute the natural log of the survival function of a Gaussian distribution using

```
np.log( scipy.stats.norm.sf(s) )
```

I need to compute the survival function for some ludicrously large values of s (maybe up to 1000), but the above function hits double point machine precision around s = 37. Is there some function I could use to compute the log of the survival function directly?

**Note:** I don't believe my underlying distribution is Gaussian out to that many sigma, but I need the survival function to compute some properties of weak signals (3-4 sigma), and I want the algorithm to do something reasonable in the presence of very strong signals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`logsf`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.logsf.html) method of [`scipy.stats.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html).

For example:

```
In [67]: from scipy.stats import norm

In [68]: norm.logsf(1000)
Out[68]: -500007.82669481222
```

Comment: Well that was easy. I don't know how I didn't see that in the docs. Thanks.